# Inherit Point of sale (POS) Module For Customization

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

Hello Odoo's Expert,

Firstly, I'm beginner in odoo(odoo v10), so i will appreciate every correction for my question.

Okay let's to the question, In Point of sale (POS) Module

[image: Pos Session Interface]

There are many function there, also button such as Payment, number for input price (Numpad Widget) etc

What I want to do is I want to disable Numpad Widget

[image: This is Numpad Widget]

SO the price of product cannot be change, besides the user has group called manager.

I know i can do that in pos.xml (addons/point_of_sale/static/src/pos.xml

[image: This is the original code]

but I dont want to modify in odoo has default code, I want to do that by inherit the odoo pos.xml like odoo qweb, form, etc

could anyone please tell me is it possible to do modify by inherit the odoo point of sale original file (i mean to create new custom module / addons) , or the only way to do modify is only change the code in original file?

[**UPDATE**]

I already disabled by inheriting of point of sale xml, but now i want get user has group in point of sales module, whether user is manager in point of sale module

I look this code in model.js

```
 var pos_users = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var user = users[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < user.groups_id.length; j++) {
                var group_id = user.groups_id[j];
                if (group_id === self.config.group_pos_manager_id[0]) {
                    user.role = 'manager';
                    break;
                } else if (group_id === self.config.group_pos_user_id[0]) {
                    user.role = 'cashier';
                }
            }
            if (user.role) {
                pos_users.push(user);
            }
            // replace the current user with its updated version
            if (user.id === self.user.id) {
                self.user = user;
            }
        }
        self.users = pos_users;
```

How can I get the user group in my /static/src/xml/myxml.xml file?

Thanks In advance.

*Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes you can modify POS modules with inheritance. For that you can refer code of POS restaurant. Once try to look in that code and create replica of that with your modification.

Comment: @KevalMehta : hy, thanks for your response,I already disabled those button , but I only want disable the button if the user has group besides "manager" in "Point of sale" module. how to know user's group in specifics module (in this case the module is Point of sale) module, Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know user's group via frontend or in backend?

Comment: I think front end, in xml file @KevalMehta

Comment: you can easily get this via js. Because in res.users model define in model.js situated under POS/static/src/js you can able to get group_id field. From there you can able to get user's group

Comment: I updated my question, I look code in js about user group but i dont know how to get the value in my xml, thanks

Comment: You can create a method in models.js. In that 'exports.order' for user group and call that method in xml.